# asp.net MVC pagination based on query

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add pagination (next/previous) to posts on an MVC news site. The posts are of type story, photoGallery, or video. The site has different pages for listing these posts, such as filtering by type (story, photoGallery, video) or issue. So I would like for my next and previous buttons to be based on whatever listing they were viewing.

**Case 1**

1. Viewing main index page (no filtering)
2. Select a story from the list [navigates to page for the story]
3. Click "next" link on page [navigates to page for the next item from the collection of all items]
4. Click "next" link on this page continues to page through the items from the collection of all items.

**Case 2**

1. Viewing Video Posts from Issue number 2
2. Select a Video from the list [navigates to page for the video]
3. Click "next" link on page [navigates to page for the next video from the collection of videos in Issue number 2]
4. Click "next" link on this page continues to page through the items from the collection of videos in Issue number 2.

The items are coming from a repository, and the different filter pages just use LINQ expressions to filter the collection of items by their type or issue. Getting the next/previous links on the first post they view is easy enough, but then from that page how can I determine what items they were viewing and somehow pass that to whatever other posts they page to?

**Controller Code**

(Index lists all, Stories filters to stories -- videos and photos are similar to the stories method)

```
public ActionResult Index(string issueUrl)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(issueUrl))
    {
        var issueItems = ItemRepository.Items.ForIssue(issueUrl);
        if (issueItems.Count() > 0)
        {
            ViewBag.IssueTitle = issueItems.First().IssueTitle;
            ViewBag.IssueUrl = issueItems.First().IssueUrl;
            return View("Index", issueItems.ForTag(Request["tag"]).ByDateDesc());
        }
        else { return NothingToShow(true); }
    }
    else
    {
        return View(ItemRepository.Items.ForTag(Request["tag"]).ByDateDesc());
    }
}

public ActionResult Stories(string issueUrl, string itemUrl)
{
    var stories = ItemRepository.Items.Stories();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemUrl))
    {
        var item = stories.ItemForUrl(itemUrl);
        if (item != null)
        {
            return View("Story", item);
        }
        else { return NothingToShow(true); }
    }

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(issueUrl))
    {
        var tempStories = stories.ForIssue(issueUrl);
        if (tempStories.Count() > 0)
        {
            stories = tempStories;
            ViewBag.IssueTitle = stories.First().IssueTitle;
            ViewBag.IssueUrl = stories.First().IssueUrl;
        }
        else { return NothingToShow(); }
    }

    return View("Index", stories.ForTag(Request["tag"]).ByDateDesc());
}
```

I am using ASP.net MVC 5. Views are strongly typed according to post type (story, photoGallery, video), or a collection of posts for the Index page.

**URL Structure**

```
/myapp/                   (Index showing stories, photoGalleries, and videos)
/myapp/23                 (Index filtered to issue 23)
/myapp/23/stories         (Issue 23 filtered to show only stories)
/myapp/stories            (All Stories)
/myapp/stories/story-url  (A single Story)
[repeat above three for photos and videos]
```

**Question**

To clarify: How can I go about creating next/previous pagination on the post pages that pages through the posts on the listing page that they were on?

**Edit**

Highlighting- the complication is that when a user navigates to a single story from a list page, I need to somehow keep the list of posts to then page through. This "list" is a filtered version, created from the repository. The list seen on Index would be different than the list seen on Stories.

Answer (score 0):

Compute your different next and previous links inside the action, send them to the view via your ViewModel, and make the buttons using these links.

Comment: To compute this, don't I need to pass something to the action that represents the list of items they are viewing, and then next and previous can be computed based on what was selected?

Comment: I don't see you needing anything more than the current page number.

Comment: @BradleyUffner "Photo Gallery 2" might be the second thing when only viewing photo galleries, but if they selected "Photo Gallery 2" from the index page that shows other posts as well, it might be the fifth item. So, a simple page number doesn't give me enough information to know what the next or previous item is. There will have to be some kind of "state" initialized when an item is selected from a list page.

Comment: The list is built by the action not by the view. I agree with @BradleyUffner.

Comment: First of all, you need to pass all the necessary information to the view through your model: like Category - can be either (story, photography, video), the PageNo which is 1 on first page load  and the total number of items in each category. Then every time Next is clicked, you will update the PageNo and query the server to get you the data for the next page in that category. Do the same when user clicks on Previous. When the user clicks on Next/Previous, you need to return back the updated PageNo. Reset PageNo back to 1 when a user selects a different Category

Comment: I've added an edit to the original question. The pagination is between single items in a complex list. If I could have a delegate property in my model that serves as a query that would accomplish what I need. But I don't think delegates can be passed to Actions.